# Bash script "Syntax Error: Unexpected end of file"

Tags: shell, unix, sh

The goal is to create a simple trash utility using a Bourne shell (it's part of an assignment). I am receiving the following error: "line 17: Syntax Error: Unexpected end of file"

I have been staring at the code for a few hours now and I can't see the mistake (probably something simple I am overlooking)

```
#!/bin/sh

if [$# == 0] ;then 
    echo "Usage: trash -l | -p | { filename }*"
else
    if $1 == '-l'; then
        dir $HOME/.trash
    else if $1=='-p'; then 
        rm $HOME/.trash/*
    else
        for i in ${} ;do 
            mv i $HOME/.trash
        done
    fi
fi
```

Thanks!

Comment: change `else if` to `elif` ? Good luck.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: nope.

Comment: More errors: Uses spaces in the if statement and use -eq when comparing integers: `if [ $# -eq 0 ]`. Use `ls`, not `dir`. Put a variable-name between the braces of `${}`. When you refer to a variable, use a `$` as in `mv $i $HOME/.trash`. And why did you stop using `[]` for your if-statements (they are not always needed but for now just use them).

Comment: Please run your code through http://shellcheck.net. Those hours would have been better spent reading the man page for your shell to learn basic syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I achieved using shellcheck:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ;then 
    echo "Usage: trash -l | -p | { filename }*"
else
    if [ "$1" = '-l' ]; then
        dir "$HOME"/.trash
    elif "$1"=='-p'; then 
        rm "$HOME"/.trash/*
    else
        for i in ${} ;do 
            mv "$i" "$HOME"/.trash
        done
    fi
```